# How can I freeze the header of a .xslx with Talend Open Studio or in java

Tags: java, excel, talend, xlsx

I would like to frezze the header (first line in excel) with Talend or java.

I've succed with the .xls extention in Talend by doing a litle trick in the excel component (TfileOutputExcel), I just put this litle code in the cell name "first cell".

```
1;writableSheet_tFileOutputExcel_2.getSettings().setVerticalFreeze(1)
```

Thank you in advance for your answers ! :)

Comment: Hello, can you give more information, what do you mean by freeze the header?

Comment: Thank you for responding, i would like to have the first line of an excel file that remains at the top even if you move down from the excel file. You can use this link to have an image to have a better idea of the issue: https://i.imgur.com/gAWCNA4.png